# Write .htaccess file to check requests from root

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with writing a **.htaccess** to help me handle requests from root, i.e. http://domain.com/index.php can handle users' requests to http://domain.com/abc/, which is from a child folder.

So, just to clarify, I want every time the users go to `http://domain.com/abc/`, my code in `http://domain.com/index.php` will handle the GET request as if it was `http://domain.com/index.php?url=abc`.

I don't have much experience working with .htaccess, hope somebody can help me :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(abc)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Just remember that above rule will work only for URI `/abc` or `/abc/`.

Comment: I got a 500 Internal Server Error when using your code, but it still works well with my previous code. I turned on mod_rewrite in Apache already :) Is there any further configuration that you didn't tell?

Comment: Oops my bad, I had a typo there, sorry about that. Please try again.